# How do you change the background color of an element?

Tags: vs-color-theme-editor

I'm going off [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes), [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules), and [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html#entity).

I have a html file:

```
<html>
    <myelm>
        this is my cool elm
    </myelm>
    <span>FOOOO</span>
</html>
```

and I want the background color of the entire myelm element, including the inner text, to be red. How do I do that?

This turns the element names red. That's something. But not what I want:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.name.tag",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#ff0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The example you're using isn't from Sublime and neither is one of the two links; are you trying to do this in Visual Studio and Sublime or just Visual Studio?

Comment: I guess VSCode uses sublimes syntax which is why I included the sublime tag. I could switch to sublime possibly. Is html element background coloring possible in sublime?

Comment: They share a common TextMate ancestor, but VSCode is using a different file format. This is technically possible in Sublime (although the default HTML Syntax doesn't apply a unique scope to tag contents) by using a `<background>` tag in the `tmTheme`; if VSCode works the same way, I would try swapping `"foreground"` for `"background"` and see what that gets you.

Comment: Same thing. It's fine, I guess. I just split the file up into multiple files so now I can tell where things are at without having to use color coding.